# AWS cost explorer group by instance type - No instance type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloud

I have came across a particular field in AWS cost explorer called "No Instance Type($)" and it says
***This category includes costs (e.g., data transfer in/out) that are not directly attributable to a specific Instance Type.

So I want to understand it more correctly that it means it is the sum of all data transfer in/out from all over all the AWS Services ?

Comment: No, it is also other things like Elastic IPs and S3 also has its own Data Transfer In/Out line in the bills. But I am not sure if VM-based services like RDS could have their Data Transfer billed there.

Comment: Yes I am also not sure about that part because this is only line specified in AWS cost explorer in very small letters.